# NSUserdefault does not exist in current context in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

As I am new to Xamarin, I am using the following code for NSUserdefaults in Xamarin but it shows "The name 'nsuserdefault' does not exist in current context"

```
public string userID
        {
            get
            {
                string value = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("userId");
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not available in your `Xamarin.Forms` project since it is available on iOS level only. Luckily the solution is quite simple.

If I understand correctly you are looking for a way to save user preferences on the device. Since you are using Xamarin.Forms I would recommend the next options that are cross-platform:

- [Application.Current.Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) - default build in mechanism in Xamarin.Forms.
- [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) - open source plugin, iOS implementation is using the `NSUserDefaults`.

If for some reason you want to use native `NSUserDefaults` you could still do it by creating an abstraction, implementing it in your iOS project and consuming it on the XF level. I already mentioned a good example [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin).